# Trato que varios inputs tengan una misma funcionalidad con una solo función Ajax ¿Cómo puedo lograr esto?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Estoy intentando lo siguiente:

Tengo los siguientes `input` con el siguiente código HTML:

```
<div class="ing_guiGrid col6">
                    <p>
                        <label for="id_observa">Observaciones:</label>
                        <textarea name="observa" cols="40" rows="10" maxlength="500" required="required" id="id_observa"></textarea>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="id_tipo_envio">Envio:</label>
                        <input type="number" name="tipo_envio" required="required" id="id_tipo_envio" class="tipo_envio">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="id_descripcion">Descripcion:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="descripcion" maxlength="150" required="required" id="id_descripcion" class="descripcion">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="id_cantidad">Cantidad:</label>
                        <input type="number" name="cantidad" min="0" value="0" required="required" id="id_cantidad" class="cantidad">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="id_peso">Peso:</label>
                        <input type="number" name="peso" min="0" value="0" step="any" required="required" id="id_peso" class="peso">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="id_precio">Tarifa:</label>
                        <input type="number" name="precio" min="0" value="0" step="any" required="required" id="id_precio" class="precio">
                    </p>
</div>
<div id="newRow"></div>
<div>
      <button id="addRow" type="button" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
textarea#id_observaciones {
    resize: none;
    height: 39px;
}
.ing_guiGrid{
    display: grid;
    gap: 20px;
}
.ing_guiGrid.col6{
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 0.5fr 2.5fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 0;
}
.ing_guiGrid.col6 input,
.ing_guiGrid.col6 textarea{
    width: 100%;
}
.ing_guiGrid.col6 p:nth-child(1){
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.ing_guiGrid input{
    width: 100%;
}
```

el cual se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y tengo su funcionalidad, que es, cuando se escribe un número en el `input` `.tipo_envio` por medio de Ajax se llama a la descripción en su respectivo `input`, el Ajax es el siguiente:

```
function buscarProducto(){
    var codigo = $(".tipo_envio").val();
    if(codigo===""){
        return false;
    }

    var path = "{% url 'api:producto_list' %}" + codigo;
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: path,
        success: function(r){
            console.log(r);
            console.log(r.estado);

            if(!r.estado){
                mensaje("Producto No Tiene Existencia o está inactivo",'orange')
                $(".tipo_envio").val("");
                $(".descripcion").val("");
                $(".precio").val("0.00");
                $(".tipo_envio").focus();
                return false;
            }

            $(".tipo_envio").val(r.id);
            $(".descripcion").val(r.descripcion);
            $(".precio").val(r.precio);
            $(".tipo_envio").focus();

        },
        error: function(a,b,c){
            console.log(a);
            if(a.status==404){
                mensaje("Producto -" + codigo + "- No Encontrado o No Existe",'red');
                $(".tipo_envio").val("");
                $(".descripcion").val("");
                $(".precio").val("0.00");
                $(".tipo_envio").focus();
            }

        }

    });
}
```

llamo a esta función con un change en Jquery:

```
$(".tipo_envio").change(function(){
        buscarProducto();
});
```

Y todo resulta bien, el problema es cuando intento usar la misma función con otros `input`, tengo un botón que agrega los elementos por medio de JavaScript:

```
 $("#addRow").click(function () {
    var html = '';
    html += '<div class="ing_guiGrid col6">';
    html += '<p><button id="removeRow" type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></button></p>';
    html += '<p><input type="number" name="tipo_envio" required="required" id="id_tipo_envio" class="tipo_envio"></p>';
    html += '<p><input type="text" name="descripcion" maxlength="150" required="required" id="id_descripcion" class="descripcion"></p>';
    html += '<p><input type="number" name="cantidad" min="0" value="0" required="required" id="id_cantidad" class="cantidad"></p>';
    html += '<p><input type="number" name="peso" min="0" value="0" step="any" required="required" id="id_peso" class="peso"></p>';
    html += '<p><input type="number" name="precio" min="0" value="0" step="any" required="required" id="id_precio" class="precio"></p>';
    html += '</div>';

    $('#newRow').append(html);
});

// remove row
$(document).on('click', '#removeRow', function () {
    $(this).closest('.ing_guiGrid').remove();
});
```

Y quiero que los `.tipo_envio` que se van agregando tengan la misma funcionalidad que el original, o sea el `input` que se ve al iniciar la página, no puedo crearle una función a cada uno ya que el usuario puede agregar hasta 100 nuevos `input`.

Lo que intenté fue meterlo dentro de un forEach a modo de que cada `.tipo_envio` pudiera llamar a la función cuando se cambia el número del campo. El código es el siguiente:

```
$('#addRow').click(function(){
    var a = document.querySelectorAll(".tipo_envio")
    a.forEach(function(e){
        e.addEventListener('change', function(){
            buscarProducto()
        })
    })
});
```

Esto sí que llamó a `buscarProducto()` y tuvo la misma funcionalidad, sin embargo, lo que pasa es que no me permite cambiar de número, por más que intente hacer que me deje cambiar el número en el campo `.tipo_envio` que se acaba de crear para cambiar la descripción, no puedo. Y me muestra la misma descripción del primer `.tipo_envio` de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos datos van dentro de un formulario, por ende los envió a una base de datos donde se guardan todos los datos que el usuario ingrese. Espero puedan ayudarme, Gracias de antemano!.

EDIT:

Ahora tengo los siguientes problemas:

Al cambiar el número en el `.tipo_envio` principal no me llama la función y no cambia la descripción:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta que pongo agrego un nuevo `.tipo_envio` y lo pongo en valor "0" cambia tanto el nuevo como el anterior `.tipo_envio`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y pasa algo similar con los demás que se van agregando:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo que en estos si pongo el número repetido no me da la descripción, por ejemplo si pongo en un `.tipo_envio` el mismo número que introduje en el anterior, no me llama la descripción correspondiente hasta que pongo un número mayor y no quiero eso por que el usuario puede agregar las veces que le sea necesario el mismo tipo de envio.

Comment: Por favor [edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/515787/edit) para agregar el HTML de esa tabla. Me parece que estás repitiendo ID en cada fila y los [ID deben ser únicos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id). Seguramente solo necesitas cambiar ID por clase y hacer algunos pequeños ajustes en la función. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/509210/54039) podría servirte de guía.

Comment: Está bien agregare mi HTML

Comment: Justo lo que me temía, estás repitiendo ID. Si bien, `document.querySelectorAll('#id-repetido');` te devuelve todos los elementos encontrados, al querer modificar el valor con `$('#id-repetido').val()` se aplica solo al primero que encuentra. La respuesta que te sugerí en el primer comentario te va a servir. Intenta adaptar el concepto en tu proyecto y, si no puedes, edita nuevamente la pregunta para poner lo que intentaste y poderte ayudar con algo más concreto.

Comment: Te refieres a cambiar el ID por un CLASS, no? lo intentaré y modificaré la pregunta

Comment: Sí, señor; es correcto.

Comment: @Triby agregué la edición que hice, alguna idea de como puedo hacer que funcione ahora?:(

Comment: Repasa el código de la pregunta completamente, porque ahora ya no se entiende. 1) Pon de nuevo todo el código tal como lo tienes ahora mismo, pues dices que has cambiado los `id` por `class` y no aparece reflejado en la misma y es muy dificil ayudarte si tenemos que reescribirlo nossotros para nuestras pruebas. 2) ¿Eso es un formulario que luego tengas que enviar datos a alguna parte o se va a quedar solo en pantalla? Lo digo porque entonces puede ser importante que cada campo de cada fila agregada tenga un id unico y no tan solo una clase 3) Agrega el CSS 4) Agrega botones y el element newRow

Comment: O sea, básicamente, haz la pregunta correcta con un [example] y no la vayas actualizando a cachos sin variar el contenido inicial si este ha sufrido cambios y podremos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Vale, entonces creo una nueva pregunta, o solamente edito esta de manera que sea más entendible?

Comment: Edita esta mejor, la puedes cambiar completamente mientras siga siendo coherente con el titulo inicial, hasta puedes cambiar el título mientras sea algo parecido. Una nueva pregunta seria si fuera un tema completamente distinto.

Comment: @masterguru Listo, lo he modificado a manera que fuera más entendible y dejé todo el código necesario: )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes el problema típico de la repetición de id y ahora también de la aplicación de la asignación de los mismos valores a una clase repetida.

Me has confirmado en los comentarios que este código te funciona y más abajo he puesto una explicación de los cambios del mismo:

```js
$(".tipo_envio").change(function(){
        buscarProducto(this.id);
});

function buscarProducto(long_id){
    var id = long_id.split("_").slice(-1);
    var codigo = $("#id_tipo_envio_" + id).val();
    if(codigo===""){
        return false;
    }

    var path = "{% url 'api:producto_list' %}" + codigo;
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: path,
        success: function(r){
            console.log(r);
            console.log(r.estado);

            if(!r.estado){
                mensaje("Producto No Tiene Existencia o está inactivo",'orange')
                $("#id_tipo_envio_" + id).val("");
                $("#id_descripcion_" + id).val("");
                $("#id_precio_" + id).val("0.00");
                $("#id_tipo_envio_" + id).focus();
                return false;
            }

            $("#id_tipo_envio_" + id).val(r.id);
            $("#id_descripcion_" + id).val(r.descripcion);
            $("#id_precio_" + id).val(r.precio);
            $("#id_tipo_envio_" + id).focus();

        },
        error: function(a,b,c){
            console.log(a);
            if(a.status==404){
                mensaje("Producto -" + codigo + "- No Encontrado o No Existe",'red');
                $("#id_tipo_envio_" + id).val("");
                $("#id_descripcion_" + id).val("");
                $("#id_precio_" + id).val("0.00");
                $("#id_tipo_envio_" + id).focus();
            }

        }

    });
}
var contador = 0
 $("#addRow").click(function () {
    contador++
    var html = '';
    html += `<div class="ing_guiGrid col6">
    <p><button id="removeRow" type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-times-circle">eliminar</i></button></p>
    <p><input type="number" name="tipo_envio[]" required="required" id="id_tipo_envio_` + contador + `" class="tipo_envio"></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="descripcion[]" maxlength="150" required="required" id="id_descripcion_` + contador + `" class="descripcion"></p>
    <p><input type="number" name="cantidad[]" min="0" value="0" required="required" id="id_cantidad_` + contador + `" class="cantidad"></p>
    <p><input type="number" name="peso[]" min="0" value="0" step="any" required="required" id="id_peso_` + contador + `" class="peso"></p>
    <p><input type="number" name="precio[]" min="0" value="0" step="any" required="required" id="id_precio_` + contador + `" class="precio"></p>
    </div>`;
    $('#newRow').append(html);

    var a = document.querySelectorAll(".tipo_envio")
    a.forEach(function(e){
        e.addEventListener('change', function(){
            buscarProducto(e.id)
        })
    })
});

// remove row
$(document).on('click', '#removeRow', function () {
    $(this).closest('.ing_guiGrid').remove();
    // contador--
});
```

```css
textarea#id_observaciones {
    resize: none;
    height: 39px;
}
.ing_guiGrid{
    display: grid;
    gap: 20px;
}
.ing_guiGrid.col6{
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 0.5fr 2.5fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 0;
}
.ing_guiGrid.col6 input,
.ing_guiGrid.col6 textarea{
    width: 100%;
}
.ing_guiGrid.col6 p:nth-child(1){
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.ing_guiGrid input{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ing_guiGrid col6">
  <p>
    <label for="id_observa">Observaciones:</label>
    <textarea name="observa[]" cols="40" rows="10" maxlength="500" required="required" id="id_observa_0"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="id_tipo_envio">Envio:</label>
    <input type="number" name="tipo_envio[]" required="required" id="id_tipo_envio_0" class="tipo_envio">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="id_descripcion">Descripcion:</label>
    <input type="text" name="descripcion[]" maxlength="150" required="required" id="id_descripcion_0" class="descripcion">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="id_cantidad">Cantidad:</label>
    <input type="number" name="cantidad[]" min="0" value="0" required="required" id="id_cantidad_0" class="cantidad">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="id_peso">Peso:</label>
    <input type="number" name="peso[]" min="0" value="0" step="any" required="required" id="id_peso_0" class="peso">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="id_precio">Tarifa:</label>
    <input type="number" name="precio[]" min="0" value="0" step="any" required="required" id="id_precio_0" class="precio">
  </p>
</div>
<div id="newRow"></div>
<div>
  <button id="addRow" type="button" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fas fa-plus">agregar</i></button>
</div>
```

**Explicación de los cambios**

Bueno, como tenias mucho código y los cambios consisten en conseguir no repetir `id` y también en usar correctamente las clases, me saltaré las repeticiones de los cambios mostrando únicamente uno de cada caso. Empecemos:

1. Tenias dos eventos `click` a la escucha para el mismo elemento. He unificado su contenido agregando uno al final del otro:

```
$('#addRow').click(function(){
```

2. En la escucha del siguiente evento, realizamos el siguiente cambio de esto:

```
        e.addEventListener('change', function(){
            buscarProducto()
        })
```

por esto:

```
        e.addEventListener('change', function(){
            buscarProducto(e.id)
        })
```

porque como decia al principio, y repetiré en varias ocasiones, ahora nos interesa que todo se relacione con el `id` de cada elemento, y la forma en que llamamos a la función `buscarProducto()` también. Por lo tanto le pasamos el valor del `id` como parámetro.

3. Por idéntico motivo modificamos esto:

```
$(".tipo_envio").change(function(){
        buscarProducto();
});
```

por esto:

```
$(".tipo_envio").change(function(){
        buscarProducto(this.id);
});
```

4. En la función buscarProducto empezamos los cambios modificando esto primero:

```
function buscarProducto(){
```

por esto:

```
function buscarProducto(long_id){
    var id = long_id.split("_").slice(-1);
```

De esta forma primero definimos que la función necesita un parámetro, que aquí llamamos `long_id`, y que cuadra con los cambios anteriores donde hemos forzado enviar el parámetro `id` en los dos casos que se llama a dicha función.

Para el cambio de la segunda línea se necesita una explicación previa. A saber. Como vamos a relacionarlo todo mediante su `id` éste no puede estar repetido, así que más adelante vamos a cambiar los `id` que necesitemos agregándoles una coletilla con un número, de este modo:  `id_tipo_envio` pasará a ser `id_tipo_envio_X` donde **X** representa un número cualquiera.

Por lo tanto, cuando recibimos un `id` como parámetro de la función, lo recibimos completo, es decir, así:  `id_tipo_envio_X`, pero no nos sirve para identificar a todos los otros *ids* relacionados con este registro, los cuales tendran la misma X y se llamarán `id_descripcion_X`, `id_precio_X`, etc.

5. Cómo hemos llamado al parámetro `long_id` ahora nos interesa sacarle la X solamente y asignarla a la variable interna `id` de la función, que usaremos más adelante de nuevo. Para ello lo hacemos de este modo:

```
    var id = long_id.split("_").slice(-1);
```

que nos parte la variable `long_id` en trozos separados por el guión bajo `_`, y eso lo hace la función `split()`, creando un array con todos ellos.  De este array tan solo nos interes el último, es decir, la X, por lo tanto lo sacamos con la función `slice()` con su parámetro `-1` que indica que queremos el último elemento de un array. O sea, la **X**, que queda asignada a la variable **id**.

6. Lo siguiente que hacemos es buscar el valor del código del producto, que antes se intentaba conseguir con esto (mal):

```
var codigo = $(".tipo_envio").val();
```

pero daba un problema, que tan solo cogia el primer valor encontrado, pues es una clase que se aplica en cada fila. Para solucionarlo empezamos a usar el `id` conseguido en el paso previo cambiando esa línea de este modo:

```
var codigo = $("#id_tipo_envio_" + id).val();
```

y con este cambio estamos consiguiendo el valor del elemento correcto identificado uniquívocamente gracias a su `id`.

7. Los siguientes cambios dentro de la función son de carrerilla, y se trata de apuntar siempre al `id` del elemento correctamente, por lo tanto alli donde viéramos referencias a cualquier `id` teniamos que agregarle la coletilla de nuevo.
   A groso modo se han cambiado estos:

```
                $(".tipo_envio").val("");
                $(".descripcion").val("");
                $(".precio").val("0.00");
                $(".tipo_envio").focus();
...
            $(".tipo_envio").val(r.id);
            $(".descripcion").val(r.descripcion);
            $(".precio").val(r.precio);
            $(".tipo_envio").focus();
...
                $(".tipo_envio").val("");
                $(".descripcion").val("");
                $(".precio").val("0.00");
                $(".tipo_envio").focus();
```

por estos:

```
                $("#id_tipo_envio_" + id).val("");
                $("#id_descripcion_" + id).val("");
                $("#id_precio_" + id).val("0.00");
                $("#id_tipo_envio_" + id).focus();
...
            $("#id_tipo_envio_" + id).val(r.id);
            $("#id_descripcion_" + id).val(r.descripcion);
            $("#id_precio_" + id).val(r.precio);
            $("#id_tipo_envio_" + id).focus();
...
                $("#id_tipo_envio_" + id).val("");
                $("#id_descripcion_" + id).val("");
                $("#id_precio_" + id).val("0.00");
                $("#id_tipo_envio_" + id).focus();
```

Como ves, ahora todo apunta a un `id` de elemento concreto e inequívoco, mientras antes lo hacia de forma repetida y solo cogia el primero que encontraba pues estaban todos duplicados.

8. Se ha agregado una nueva variable global que nos hara de contador y que irá generando las X de las que estamos hablando todo el rato:

```
var contador = 0;
```

9. Se ha agregado esto dentro de la escucha del evento `click` de **#addRow** para que incremente el valor de **contador** en cada click realizado, al principio de la llamada.

```
contador++
```

10. Del mismo modo que en paso 7 (siempre es lo mismo ahora), dentro del evento `click` de **#addRow** he cambiado esto:

```
    html += '<p><input type="number" name="tipo_envio" required="required" id="id_tipo_envio" class="tipo_envio"></p>';
    html += '<p><input type="text" name="descripcion" maxlength="150" required="required" id="id_descripcion" class="descripcion"></p>';
    html += '<p><input type="number" name="cantidad" min="0" value="0" required="required" id="id_cantidad" class="cantidad"></p>';
    html += '<p><input type="number" name="peso" min="0" value="0" step="any" required="required" id="id_peso" class="peso"></p>';
    html += '<p><input type="number" name="precio" min="0" value="0" step="any" required="required" id="id_precio" class="precio"></p>';
```

por esto:

```
    <p><input type="number" name="tipo_envio[]" required="required" id="id_tipo_envio_` + contador + `" class="tipo_envio"></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="descripcion[]" maxlength="150" required="required" id="id_descripcion_` + contador + `" class="descripcion"></p>
    <p><input type="number" name="cantidad[]" min="0" value="0" required="required" id="id_cantidad_` + contador + `" class="cantidad"></p>
    <p><input type="number" name="peso[]" min="0" value="0" step="any" required="required" id="id_peso_` + contador + `" class="peso"></p>
    <p><input type="number" name="precio[]" min="0" value="0" step="any" required="required" id="id_precio_` + contador + `" class="precio"></p>
```

donde hay que fijarse en el cambio de los `id=` que todos han pasado a ser del tipo:

```
id_AAAAA_` + contador
```

para identificarlos de inequívoca durante su creación en cada click.

Con todos estos cambios hemos conseguido solucionar tu problema, tal como me has confirmado en los comentarios.

Si has leido hasta aquí dejame un comentario para saber que lo has hecho, sino la proxima vez no te lo cuento y no te ayudo :-)

Comment: Gracias por ayudarme:'D, solo que ahora tengo otros problemas con el resultado:(, usé el código tal y como me lo diste y hay como unos especies de BUGS y no quiero eso, deje ya todo redactado en la pregunta.

Comment: Creo que me he equivocado aqui:  `buscarProducto(this.value);`... cambialo por `buscarProducto(this.id);` y dime si eso lo arregla, gracias

Comment: No amigo, sigue dandome el mismo problema:(

Comment: Vale, he editado un poco más mi respuesta, vuelve a probar, por favor

Comment: Eso es todo amigo! Muchas gracias, me sirve:'D. Gracias.

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro :-)  Saludos!  (cuando tenga algo de tiempo lo explicare de forma breve)

Comment: Está bien, muchas gracias una vez más.

Comment: Vale, ya he agregado una explicacion un poco extensa de los cambios, pero claro, es que eran muchos. Saludos!

Comment: He leído hasta el final xd, desconocía el uso de split() y slice(). muchas gracias por ayudarme y darme una explicación concisa que también me sirvió para adquirir más conocimiento.

Comment: Gracias por leértelo!  Serás el único, ya verás, hay mucho cacho de respuesta :-)  pero bueno, mi idea era que **tu** aprendieras pues en nada me motiva darte el pescado y que luego no sepas pescar y pases hambre ;-) saludos!